# I don't understand one of the steps in solving this equation.

Tags: radicals

I'm very rusty... it's been a few years since I've touched radicals and algebra. I had to solve for $k$ in the course of a Physics problem, and I realized I didn't remember how to do this.

$$10=\sqrt{\frac k {0.05}}$$

So I went to Wolfram Alpha and checked the steps. The result was given as 5, but I was confused by this step:

$$10=4.47214 \sqrt k$$

I'm confused by where 4.47214 came from.

Sorry if this is too basic for this forum. I might be missing something that is glaringly obvious...

Comment: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{0.05}}\approx4.47214$

Comment: By hand, I would not do it the Alpha way. Square both sides. We get $100=\frac{k}{0.05}$. Now multiply both sides by $0.05$.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses, I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

Well $1/0.05 = 1/(1/20) = 20$ and so $\sqrt{k/0.05} = \sqrt{20k} = \sqrt{20}\cdot \sqrt{k}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$10=\sqrt{\frac{k}{0.05}}$$
$$100=\frac{k}{0.05}$$
$$100(0.05)=k$$
$$k=5$$